# Showing View from one Parent activity in all child Activity in android

Tags: android, inheritance, android-recyclerview

I have a BaseActivity that extends Activity having a RecyclerView in it.
I want to inherit this RecyclerView in all Activities. So for every activity im using, it extends BaseActivity.

But if I use a different XML layout using **setContentView** on Child Activity, the RecyclerView from BaseActivity is not visible.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        baseRecyclerModel itemsData[] = { new baseRecyclerModel("Help",R.drawable.help),
                new baseRecyclerModel("Delete",R.drawable.delete),
                new baseRecyclerModel("Cloud",R.drawable.cloud)};


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        baseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new   baseRecyclerAdapter(itemsData);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
```

**ChildActivity1.java**

```
public class ChildActivity1 extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_mobile_number);



    }
```

What might be a possible workaround or solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't have to call `setContentView()` in your BaseActivity.java.
make a separate function for initializing `RecyclerView` in BaseActivity.java (e.g. `create()`). in ChildActivity1 call `setContentView()` and `create()`.
then include activity_base.xml in activity_get_mobile_number.xml

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void create() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        baseRecyclerModel itemsData[] = { new baseRecyclerModel("Help",R.drawable.help),
            new baseRecyclerModel("Delete",R.drawable.delete),
            new baseRecyclerModel("Cloud",R.drawable.cloud)};


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        baseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new   baseRecyclerAdapter(itemsData);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}

public class ChildActivity1 extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_mobile_number);
        create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `setContentView` in your `ChildActivity`, you effectively replace the `BaseActivity` layout with the new one. In order to have the `RecyclerView` available in `ChildActivity`, you would need to include it `activity_get_mobile_number.xml` in as well.

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) about the `include` and `merge` tags.

The idea would be to have a separate generic layout file that you would include in both the `BaseActivity` and `ChildActivity` layouts. Then, move all your code in a method, and call it in the subclass :

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        setupRecyclerView();
    }

    protected void setupRecyclerView(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        baseRecyclerModel itemsData[] = { new baseRecyclerModel("Help",R.drawable.help),
            new baseRecyclerModel("Delete",R.drawable.delete),
            new baseRecyclerModel("Cloud",R.drawable.cloud)};

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        baseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new   baseRecyclerAdapter(itemsData);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}


public class ChildActivity1 extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_mobile_number);
        super.setupRecyclerView(),
    }

}
```